# Any way to link JS library in external JS file?

Tags: javascript, three.js, libraries

It may be confusing but what I mean is that I have this code in my main .html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="css/fpsgame.css" rel="StyleSheet">
    <script src="js/fpsgame.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I want to create something in 3d (set the scene, set up the camera, create a cube) in the fpsgame.js and keep the script *away* from the .html file. However, what do I have to do if I want to use Three.js methods or methods from a library inside the fpsgame.js file?

In other words, how would I include the three.js library into the fpsgame.js file, which is not in the .html file?

Comment: fpsgame.js *is* in your HTML, but it should be after three.js (and possibly after jquery).

Comment: so if I put fpsgame.js after three.js and jquery, will I be able to use the three.js library in my fpsgame.js script?

Comment: oh never mind. I was dumb.

Comment: I got it now, putting the libraries before the fpsgame.js includes the libraries into the file.

Comment: Exactly, it's just a matter of ordering the files